# Start of Networks brings "Permission denied"

Tags: boot, networking, server, netplan

I have made some changes to my kvm server. Some machines were installed and a DNS server was set up.

Suddenly during the boot process some messages appear and the network does not start.

```
blkmapd[726]: open pipe file /run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/blocklayout failed: No such file or directory
systemd-networkd[732]: Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied
systemd-networkd[732]: Could not connect to bus: Permission denied
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Configuration.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Wait for Network to be Configured.
systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Job systemd-networkd-wait-online.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
```

So, during startup then network remains down.

```
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: +---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: |  Device |   Up  |  Address  |    Mask   | Scope |     Hw-Address    |
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: +---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: | enp89s0 | False |     .     |     .     |   .   | 88:ae:dd:04:0e:1e |
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: |    lo   |  True | 127.0.0.1 | 255.0.0.0 |  host |         .         |
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: |    lo   |  True |  ::1/128  |     .     |  host |         .         |
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: |   wlo1  | False |     .     |     .     |   .   | bc:09:1b:83:95:ff |
cloud-init[754]: ci-info: +---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
```

If I go to the server directly and enter `sudo netplan try` followed by `sudo netplan apply` the network works again. Does anyone have an idea where I should look?

```
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd-networkd[1993]: br0: Re-configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-br0.network
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd-networkd[1993]: br0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd-networkd[1993]: enp89s0: Re-configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp89s0.network
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd-networkd[1993]: enp89s0: Re-configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp89s0.network
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd-networkd[1993]: br0: Re-configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-br0.network
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd-networkd[1993]: br0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas sudo[2040]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 09 09:00:08 atlas systemd[1]: Reloading Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
```

My netplan/00-installer-config.yaml looks like this:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
#network:
#  ethernets:
#    enp89s0:
#      dhcp4: true
#  version: 2
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    enp89s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      #addresses: [192.168.1.239/24]
      #gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      #mtu: 1500
      #nameservers:
      #  addresses: [8.8.8.8]

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp89s0]
      addresses: [192.168.0.15/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```